# Client certificate in HTTP (Windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have got .crt and .key for client certificate of HTTPClient. But I dont find any information / examples how to use it. I have got two variants of use.

First: .pfx from .crt and .key, then install it and load to filter.

```
public static async Task Init()
{
  HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
  StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///client-cert.pfx"));
  await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
    CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)), "", ExportOption.NotExportable, KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent, InstallOptions.None, "name");
  IReadOnlyList<Certificate> certs = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(new CertificateQuery() { FriendlyName = "name" });
  filter.ClientCertificate = certs.FirstOrDefault();
  Client = new HttpClient(filter);
}
```

It works, but fails WACK, because

> Package cant contain .pfx or .snk files, remove them and try again.

Second: Load Certificate class from file. HTTPFilter throws exception, because of .crt doesnt contains private key. Nor constructor, not methods of Certificate class contains any ways to set private key from .key file or something else.

```
public static async Task Init()
{
  HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
  StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Certificates/client.crt"));
  Certificate cert = new Certificate(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file));
  filter.ClientCertificate = certs.FirstOrDefault();
  Client = new HttpClient(filter);
}
```

So, how can I use .crt and .key for authorization client on server.
[Link](http://www.piotrwalat.net/client-certificate-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-store-apps/) has not help me, because of error of WACK. I have added OID to my cert and use same code. Certificates are set as Content and Copy Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just renamed pfx extension of file, works finally.

Comment: Can you tell me more about what you mean? Did you change the name to .crt? What if there is a password?

Comment: @tofutim ImportPfxDataAsync with GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///client-cert.notpfx"));

Answer (score 0):

Just install the certificates into the Windows Certificate Store on the client.